# unmarshal missing field as empty map

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

```
type FieldDefinition struct {
    Name        string   `json:"name"`
    Description string   `json:"description"`

    Aspects map[string]string `json:"aspects"`
}

func (f *FieldDefinition) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var tmp struct {
        Name        string   `json:"name"`
        Description string   `json:"description"`

        Aspects map[string]string `json:"aspects"`
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if tmp.Aspects == nil {
        tmp.Aspects = make(Aspects)
    }

    *f = tmp

    return nil
}
```

If I unmarshal`{"description": "desc","name": "name"}` without `aspects` field, the `Aspects` will be nil.

It can be solved by add the `UnmarshalJSON` function.

However there are two problems.
One is that if one strcut embeds `FieldDefinition` such as

```
type PropertyDefinition struct {
    FieldDefinition
    SourceName string     `json:"sourceName"`
}
```

`json.Unmarshal` will call `FieldDefinition.UnmarshalJSON` and left `SourceName` untouched.

I can add `PropertyDefinition.UnmarshalJson` also, but it is infectious.

The other is that the `tmp` struct is repeating `FieldDefinition` which is minor and I can bear it.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27589 is related.

---

So my problem is that the user may enter `{"description": "desc","name": "name"}` and they want to get `{"description": "desc","name": "name","aspects":{}}` but now `{"description": "desc","name": "name","aspects":null}` is returned instead.

Comment: 1.create a new type of map[string]string such as notnilmap
2.impl notnilmap.UnmarshalJSON, notnilmap will be not nil

Comment: @Para  Actually I did create `type Aspects map[string]string` and implemented UnmarshalJSON, but it won't be called if aspects is missing in the input json.

Comment: You did not ask a question, so I'm just guessing. Use plain encoding/json.Unmarshal but wrap it in a helper function which replace a nil Aspects with an empty map.

Comment: @Evilolipop to avoid repeating the type's definition inside `UnmarshalJSON` you can declare a new type _derived_ from the original type, i.e. https://go.dev/play/p/glQVGsfYlV7. But, short of forking the stdlib and adding your own features, I don't think there's a way to avoid the `nil` map with just the native types. You'd have to create a custom type with accessors that lazily initialize the map and never return nil.

Answer (score 0):

> the tmp struct is repeating FieldDefinition which is minor and I can bear it.

You shouldn't need to do this. You can create another type over `FieldDefinition` and the new type won't have the `UnmarshalJSON` method, e.g.:

```golang
func (f *FieldDefinition) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type newType FieldDefinition

    var target newType
    target.Aspects = make(map[string]string) // ensures map always non-nil
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // TODO: handle map merge if f.Aspects is already populated
    *f = (FieldDefinition)(target)

    return nil
}
```

For your other question regarding `FieldDefinition.UnmarshalJSON` becoming exposed for structs that embed it, unfortunately there is not a good way to work around that if using `encoding/json` from the std lib a requirement. If having it as a named field rather than embedding if an option, then this would no longer be a problem.

But I don't think you need the custom `UnmarshalJSON` to ensure that the map is always non-nil to begin with.

If the `Aspects` map is expected to be read-only to consumers of it, then go's handling of a nil map should already work with this use case well, because reading a key from a nil map will not panic - it will just behave as if the key isn't there:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var m map[string]string = nil
    value, exists := m["foo"]
    fmt.Println("value", value)
    fmt.Println("exists", exists)
    // prints
    // value 
    // exists false
}
```

Furthermore, if the consumer needs to disambiguate whether the `Aspects` map was set or not, they now can check if that struct field is `nil` or not.

So that was assuming that the `Aspects` map was only going to be read-only.

If consumers are also going to be updating the `Aspects` map after JSON decoding, then you could either 1) expect the consumers to be responsible for checking for nil and instantiating the map if needed, or 2) provide a helper method, e.g. `FieldDefinition.SetAspectField(string, string)` that could handle instantiating the map for consumers.

Edit: mention handling map merge in `FieldDefinition.UnmarshalJSON` if `Aspect` map was already non-nil